# Can i call dialog box on popup screen in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

In my blackberry application i make one popup screen which is popup on click of menu item. on that popup screen i took one button. Now i want to show alert dialog box on click of that button.How to do this ?Plz tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context)
{

    if(field.equals(your button object))
    {
        Dialog.alert("Your message");
}
}
```